# Angular Directive - Accessing children

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a parent and inside generating children with an ngFor loop. I want to place a directive on the parent which has access to all its childs.

```
<div appMyDirective>
    <div *ngFor="..."></div>
</div>
```

**How to get access to all children from that directive (e.g. something like QueryList) ?**

NOTE: I need to keep updated when a new child element is inserted.

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[appMyDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective {

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef) { }

  // How to access all children (DOM Elements) and stay updated about changes???
}
```

Comment: By accessing childs, do you mean accessing child's component instance or DOM element?

Comment: Looking for all DOM Elements and I want to keep updated when somethings changed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular directives can not use `ViewChild` or `ViewChildren`.
Instead you can access the native dom element using Dependency Injection inside the directive and use `MutationObserver` api to listen for changes. for example see the attached code snippet.

[Full Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzfrsh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appWatcher]'
})
export class WatcherDirective {
  observer
  constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {
    console.log('Watcher Attached', elem)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var observerOptions = {
      childList: true,
      attributes: true,
      subtree: true //Omit or set to false to observe only changes to the parent node.
    }
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(this.callback);
    this.observer.observe(this.elem.nativeElement, observerOptions);

  }

  private callback(mutationList, observer) {
    mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
      switch (mutation.type) {
        case 'childList':
          /* One or more children have been added to and/or removed
             from the tree; see mutation.addedNodes and
             mutation.removedNodes */
          console.log('Child Added or removed');
          break;
      }
    });

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.observer.disconnect();
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice approach. Thank you! Is there any quiker solution if the inner element generated with ngFor is an Angular Component?

Comment: One way would be to monitor the itertable which is passed as input to ngFor directive. By monitoring I mean constantly checking for changes in itertable inside ngDoCheck but it won't be efficient. Thats all I can think of :)